# How to concat javascript array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let A = ["u23", "c35",-----so on];

let B = ["123", "234", ---- so on];
```

both a and b indexes count are 100 and same

Expected output `C = ["u23,123", "c35,234", ---- so on]`;

I need to achieve output in very few steps without using complex steps of for loop.

ECMAScript 6 and above also will be fine.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I know using for loop and concating string of same index. I think my approach doesnt meet standards

Comment: Well, you can't avoid looping that's for sure.

Comment: What's wrong with `let C = A.map((el, i) => el + "," + B[i]);`?

Comment: I think it will help you!

var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var children = hege.concat(stale);

OUTPUT: Cecilie,Lone,Emil,Tobias,Linus

Comment: You have to run at least one loop.

Comment: I need the standard solution for performing millions records within friction of milliseconds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to loop at least once - no other option. This is one of the possible solutions:

```js
let A = ["u23", "c35", "d34"];
let B = ["123", "234", "345"];

let C = A.map((el, i) => el + "," + B[i]);
console.log(C);
```

The above solution may be improved by using a standard `for-loop`:

```
let C = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++){
  C.push(A[i] + "," + B[i]);
}
```

and you can improve it further by modifying one of the input arrays instead of creating a new array:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++){
  A[i] += "," + B[i];
}
```

You can compare the performance of each of the three above in the repl I've created [here.](https://repl.it/repls/OnerlookedMysteriousInversion)

After a few runs, you'll notice that the last method is the fastest. It's because in the second example there's a new array `C` created and it has length of `0`. With every `.push()`, the array has to be stretched which takes time. In the third example, you already have an array with the right size and you only modify its entries.

The thing which will always steal time is the string concatenation. You can play with my solutions by replacing the string concatenation with simple addition (as numbers) and you'll see that it makes the operation much faster. I hope it sheds some light on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
let newArr =[];
A.forEach((el, index)=> {
  newArr.push(el);
  newArr.push(B[index]);
}
```

The newArr is now in your required format.